# Batch Contour Process Broken in New Update?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

When I try to run the batch processing tool for contours, it does not give me the option to save the contours as a file. This stops me from running the tool all together. Has anyone else encountered this bug in 3.12.2?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you add a destination to the "additional creation options" field?

Comment: nothing, those are additional gdal commands. Doesnt let me save the file. I think its  a bug with the latest release.

Comment: I'm asking because with 3.10 the dialogue looks the same.

Comment: I just tried the batch in 3.10 and added an output-file to the field to the right and it worked. So this is more an issue of wrong labelling but a real bug. Please try with 3.12 and report back.